# Fire ajax multiple times

Tags: jquery, html

> How do I get this ajax function to fire for each input field? Currently It only fires for the first field and no others without the page being refreshed.

html:

```
<input id='item_name_1' value='item_name' onclick='test("1",  "item_name");'/>
<input id='item_value_2' value='item_value' onclick='test("2", "item_value");'/>
```

Jquery:

```
   function test(id, field_name){

    $('#'+field_name+'_'+id).keyup(function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "/admin/shop/update_harmonized_details",
            data:{
                id: id,
                field_name: field_name,
                field_value: $('#'+field_name+'_'+id).val()
            },
            success: function(resp){
                if(resp.msg == 'Success'){
                    alert('Value Updated');
                }
            }
        })
    });
}
```

Comment: Is there a typo in your example?

Comment: Yes,  i've udpated

Comment: See my edit. You are using the `onclick` listener in order to create another listener which is really strange. Technically that would attach a listener each time the user clicked the input, potentially creating multiple ajax calls on the same field. It's just not the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input id='item_name_1' value='item_name' class="listenToMe" />
<input id='item_value_2' value='item_value' class="listenToMe" />

 $('.listenToMe').keyup(function(){
     var value = $(this).val();
     var fieldID = $(this).attr('id').split('_');
     var id = fieldID[2];
     var name = fieldID[0] + '_' + fieldID[1];
     console.log('Value: value');
     console.log('ID:'+ id);
     console.log('Name:'+name);
 });
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vyeL9xu1/

If you wanted to avoid parsing the `id` attribute you could just use `data` attributes and reference the values with `$(selector).data('attributename')`. So like you could add `data-fieldname` to the input and reference it with `$(this).data('fieldname')`.

Additionally it looks like you are updating data based on 'keyup'. AJAX calls are asynchronous and won't necessarily reach, process, or finish when you expect. You could potentially run into problems here. If someone typed in 'John' it would be sent to the server in that order, but o or h could get there last and then it wouldn't save it correctly. It would be best to either provide a save button or only fire a new event after the previous is complete, something like that.

Comment: The original contained a few typos that have been corrected, I dont think the issue is in the input fields

Comment: You've changed it like 10 times now. Why can't you just post what is actually not working.

Comment: I'm trying to strip out the php variables, apologies for the multiple edits

Comment: I'll write you a better way to make the listener, what you are doing is a bit crazy, using 2 listeners when you only need 1.

Comment: To your edit: Im adding a timer to only fire ajax x seconds after the user has finished typing

Comment: Ok, as long as you are taking that into account.